# Can completely filling all the bytes with 8 significant bits of data, be a (good) way to reduce file sizes?

Tags: file, bit-manipulation, compression

I have this idea stuck in my mind for months now. When I search the internet for data compression techniques, I find that everyone is talking about removing the bytes that go unnoticed by humans or finding the repetitive patterns and re-encoding the bits and bytes so that the file size is reduced. I have very limited knowledge in the field of data compression, hence this question.

While inspecting the bit patterns of multiple MPEG-4 media files, I noticed that all 256 kinds of 8-bit patterns occur almost same number of times. That means, 255 kinds of patterns that make up 95% (or more) of this file require at most 7 bits but are taking more. If a byte stores `00001011`, the first four bits are redundant and safe to remove (correct me at this point if I am wrong). What if we remove those insignificant bits and fill up the space with significant bits of other bytes? I know the challenges if we do this. We'll need a method to get the original bit patterns with all its redundancy so it could later be understood by media players. Can we come up with an algorithm that removes the redundant bits  and stores some references (encode) to help separate the "merged" bytes and later get back the original bytes (decode) using those references? What can you say about the "stored references"? How effective and space efficient they can be? I hope I explained it well. If not, please let me know.

Example:
Let's assume a file with 8 bytes of data in it. Bytes are like the following:

1. `00010101`
2. `11110000`
3. `10101010`
4. `01010101`
5. `00000001`
6. `00000110`
7. `10111110`
8. `00001111`

Have a look at 1st, 4th, 5th, 6th and 8th bytes. We don't really need 8 bits to represent the data that it represents now. Those bytes are padded with zeros, taking up more space to complete the octet. I am going to remove the padded bits from first byte, that would make space for 3 bits. In those 3 bits, I'm going to store first 3 bits of second byte. Then the first two bytes become:

1. `11110101`
2. `00010000`

After removing all redundant bits, we end up saving 16 bits:

1. `11110101`
2. `10110000` - 101 came from 3rd byte
3. `10101010` - 101 came from 4th byte. Note that 4th byte itself has an insignificant bit
4. `11100101` - 1 and 110 came from 5th and 6th bytes
5. `10111110` - entire 7th byte
6. `00001111` - padded with zeros because the file ends here

What I did above might be hard to understand. In simple terms, I am clearing up the space by removing redundant bits (padded zeros) and then filling it with significant bits of next byte. I'm thinking about the possibility of an algorithm  that first calculates and stores some data (that obviously takes less than 16 bits in memory) and later uses it to decode the "merged bytes" to bring out the original 8 byte file that we began our example with.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if all 256 different bytes are equally likely then you just proved that there *isn't* much redundancy (at least not 0th order)

Comment: @harold think about the patterns that require less than 8 bits (7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, or 1 but not 8). How do we represent 15 in binary? It is `1111`. That's it. How is 15 represented in memory? `00001111`. As you can see first four bits from left are redundant. To keep it simple, let's assume that a media file has 20,000 bytes that represent the number 15 when base is changed to 10. All those 20,000 bytes are padded with four zeros which are absolutely insignificant. Now, if we could somehow replace the insignificant bits with significant bits of other bytes, won't that reduce size of the file?

Comment: *if* you could do that yes, but if a byte had a uniform probability distribution then the top four zeroes are significant and represent 4 bits worth of information (namely the fact that you have four zeroes there). You could use a flag for each byte to say whether you stored it normally or with the top 4 bits removed, that flag carries about 1/3rd of a bit worth of information and would actually expand the average size of a byte from 8 bits to 8.09 bits. That it doesn't help is a direct result of values < 16 being too rare to treat them specially.

Comment: And that that flag costs only a third of a bit is a result of it being false 15/16th of the time and true only 1/16th of the time. If it was 50/50 then it would cost a full bit. An other way to look at the original data here is that all the *bits* (if you decompose the bytes) have a 50/50 probability distribution and thus all cost a full bit.

Comment: @harold I do understand that the bits that I am referring to as insignificant may actually be significant. I would call this my poor choice of words. Have a look at the example I just added in the question. When the file is "encoded" we are just removing the padding bits but they'll be recovered and bytes will be separated to get back the original, untouched bytes in this 8-byte file. I am wondering if there's any mathematical formula that results in a single (32-bit/64-bit) value that would be enough to get back information worth more than 32-bits/64-bits.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you also need to mark somehow *which* bits you removed, otherwise the original data cannot be recovered, and it is exactly that marking that ruins the whole thing (though it *would actually work* if the data was originally biased towards low values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in general to simply remove the leading zero bits from values while retaining unambiguous decode and unconditionally reducing the size. While it might seem obvious to humans that `00001` is "simply 1" in the same way that 0000123 is "simply 123" - this isn't really the case when considering binary byte values. In fact, `0` and `1` are symmetric here: why not ask how to remove the leading ones?

Of course, if there are many leading zeros (more than you'd expect from uniformly distributed bytes), you could certainly compress the data with various existing techniques such as entropy coding - but just "some" occurrences of many leading zeros in byte values doesn't mean the data is compressible.

Imagine if it were possible: you could apply your technique repeatedly, until no bytes with leading zeros existed. Then you could apply NOT (invert each bit) to the data, at which point every byte would have leading zeros<sup>1</sup>, and you can keep applying your process, repeating until you have achieved infinite compression. Once you propose infinite compression, you can be pretty sure your technique doesn't work in general.

---

<sup>1</sup> It is important to note that this step is reversible, since you can apply it at decode time when there are only bytes with leading zeros.